# Image denoising

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, aruco

I need to understand what type of noise is added when light directly reflected from the region of interest. Based on the added noise , how can it be removed.? In my case , I am trying to detect an aruco marker.

[image]

Comment: Whatever the noise is, your image is overexposed, the saturated pixels indicate data is irretrievably lost. You need to start by adjusting the imaging system to avoid overexposure.

Comment: You can't remove overexposure, but you should be able to detect the marker in this particular image if that's what you want. To do that, you could threshold the image to black and white, invert the colors, apply some dilation, then select the largest connected component that is not touching the edge of the image.